# Google OAuth2.0 redirected URI missing Hash (#) and path

Tags: web, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am implementing OAuth 2.0 with Google API's, but the redirect Uri from Google is missing the hash (#) and path. Which causes my parsing to fail. I am building for Web Browsers.

My Request URI to Google:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4002%2Fsso-callback&response_type=token&state=C2ubRxTMwv&client_id=...`

The `redirect_uri` decodes to `http://localhost:4002/sso-callback`

Google's Redirect URI:
`http://localhost:4002/state=C2ubRxTMwv&access_token=...`
Which is missing both the `/sso-callback` path and the `#` needed to distinguish the OAuth params when using `response_type=token`

Google API Settings:
[image: Google Console Settings]

Not sure if this is a config issue, or a Google issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I submit this URL by pasting it in the address bar in Chrome:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://mail.google.com/&response_type=token&client_id=111111-aaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com&state=1&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback
```

I receive a redirect to

```
 http://localhost:3000/callback#state=1&access_token=ya29.A0ARrdaM-tPsT7jLIaCoVdhHo5vW71tYF1Z4ESfNNzNAh6SN7e_a4x24V0HVu4M427KF3bpWk8-Sm37oUxUHDpA-mMGJrAQPHgMlDA0suMVW2R0WBR_9vQiaPf8cMB8Tna8EH9wLSrm58PG3g30HJWUio1Ytyh&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=https://mail.google.com/
```

A few notes: Google auth server seems to only use the first redirect URI configured in Google Console. In your case it is

```
http://localhost:4002
```

Try placing your desired redirect URI

```
http://localhost:4002/sso-callback
```

in the first position in the Console.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was an SSR redirect that was breaking the urls that I did not know about. The answer by Delta George got me to try out a few other urls which made the issue clear.